# Is the tangent bundle of an oriented surface plus a trivial bundle trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $\Sigma$ be an oriented closed surface and $E$ be the direct sum of $T\Sigma$ with a trivial line bundle. Is $E$ a trivial rank $3$ vector bundle?

For genus $0$ and $1$ the answer is yes since one easily finds trivializations. For genus $\geq 2$, I can't find a trivialization, but $E$ has no non-vanishing characteristic class either to disprove the trivialness.

Comment: You can view $E$ as the pullback of the (trivial) tangent bundle of $\Bbb R^3$ for some embedding $i:\Sigma\hookrightarrow \Bbb R^3$. You get $i^*(T_{\Bbb R^3})\simeq T_{\Sigma}\oplus\nu$, where $\nu$ is the normal bundle, and is the trivial line bundle by orientability of $\Sigma$. Hence $E$ is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You may embed your oriented closed surface into $\mathbb R^3$ in the usual way.

Then the normal bundle is trivial, and of course the tangent bundle of $\mathbb R^3$ is trivial, so that the same is true of its restriction to $\Sigma$.

Thus we find that indeed, $$T\Sigma \oplus \text{ rank one trivial (i.e. normal bundle 
to $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb R^3$) }$$ $$ = \text{ rank three trivial (i.e. restriction to $\Sigma$
of $T\mathbb R^3$) }.$$